# How to Get List of all Laravel 5 Views Included in Response

Tags: php, laravel

I was wondering if there was a way that I could list all the views load / included / extended in a response?

I know of laravel-debugbar, but I'd like to do it from within my code for Unit Testing purposes.

Just to clarify: I'm not looking to list all of the views in my resources folder. I'd like to get a list of all views used in the current response/request.

Thanks!

Comment: Deleted my answer, sorry I don't know about the way you want it.

Comment: @aqq Aw :(  You didn't have to do that. Someone might have found it helpful.

Comment: Oops, undeleted now! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar for myself. It's not perfect. Create the following route with function:

```
  Route::get('list-views', function(){
  $full_path = 'FULL-PATH-TO-YOUR-LARAVEL-VIEWS-FOLDER'; //LIKE /home/account/www/resources/views/

  if(!is_dir($full_path))
    return 'Views directory not found';

  $files = scandir($full_path);
  unset($files[0]);
  unset($files[1]);

  if(($key = array_search('emails', $files)) !== false) {
    unset($files[$key]);
  }

  foreach($files AS $file){
    $link = str_replace('.blade.php','',$file);
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a>'.'<br>';
  }
});
```

What this function does is checks if the views path exists which you define in the variable $full_path, scans that directory for view files. Now, `list-views` will list all available views.

Comment: Thank you for your code.  But what I'm attempting to do is to list all of the views that are loaded during a request.

So if I were to go to route '/test' I want to see all of the views that the route uses when it returns a response.

Answer (score 0):

laravel debugbar does that, but in my case i cant find a way to list all the views under the same url in one go, so if anyone nows how i would deeply appreciate it.

```
// EventServiceProvider@boot()

app('events')->listen('composing:*', function ($view, $data = []) {
    $url = url()->current();
    $view   = $data[0];
    $name   = $view->getName();
    $path = ltrim(str_replace(base_path(), '', realpath($view->getPath())), '/');

    logger([$url=>$path]);
});
```

another way could be but this will only display the main view "not the nested or parent"

```
// EventServiceProvider@boot()

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Events\RequestHandled;

app('events')->listen(RequestHandled::class, function ($event) {
    $request  = $event->request;
    $response = $event->response;

    $check = !$request->ajax() &&
        !$request->pjax() &&
        $request->isMethodCacheable() &&
        $response->isSuccessful();

    if ($check) {
        $view = $response->original;
        $path = ltrim(str_replace(base_path(), '', realpath($view->getPath())), '/');

        logger([$request->url(), $path]);
    }
});
```

you can also get the view from a middleware but this will only display the main view same as b4

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $check = !$request->ajax() &&
        !$request->pjax() &&
        $request->isMethodCacheable() &&
        $response->isSuccessful();

    if ($check) {
        $view = $response->original;
        $path = ltrim(str_replace(base_path(), '', realpath($view->getPath())), '/');

        logger([$request->url(), $path]);
    }

    return $response;
}
```